# Kendo UI Grid: if I make changes and save them, I can still cancel them afterwards. How to lock them in?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid bound to a local data source. If I make some changes and click on "Save changes", and then I click on "Cancel changes", the changes are rolled back. I expected them to be "locked in" because I saved them.

Furthermore, if I make a change, save it, make another change, save again and finally cancel, both changes are rolled back.

See UPDATED fiddle, with problem and solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/q24ennne/7/

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
window.gridData = [
{ id: 1, text: "Uno" }, 
{ id: 2, text: "Dos" }, 
{ id: 3, text: "Tres" }, 
{ id: 14, text: "Catorce" }, 
];

(function() {
    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
      toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
      editable: true,
      saveChanges: function(e) {
        gridData = $('#grid').getKendoGrid().dataSource.data();
        $('#grid').getKendoGrid().refresh();
        console.log("gridData:");
        console.log(gridData);
      },
      columns: [{
        field: "text",
        title: "No."
      }],
      dataSource: {
        data: gridData,
      }
    });
})();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a schema for your datasource that specifies which property is the id of each item. In your case this happens to also be called "id" so add this:

```
dataSource: {
  data: gridData,
  schema: {
    model: { id: "id" }
  }
}
```

The grid will then correctly track and keep your saved changes.

Comment: Thanks NigelK, that was spot on! I updated the fiddle to include your solution (commented out so that the error can be reproduced).